# Checking whether a user is on the donors list

Tags: php, mysqli, sql-injection

I was wondering if I could please get some justification if the PHP code I wrote using Mysqli prepared statements would be able to withstand SQL injection attacks.

I have one field that gets a value from a form. Code works 100% fine, just want to make sure it is secure against SQL injection.

```
$steaminput = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'steamid_user', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$conn = mysqli_connect(host, user, pass, table);
$sql = "SELECT username, activated, expiration_date FROM donors WHERE steam_id=?";

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $steaminput);

mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username_res, $activated_res, $expiration_res);



  while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
    $data = array('username'=>$username_res, 'activated'=>$activated_res, 'expiration_date'=>$expiration_res);
  }


mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($conn);
//I use array information from retreival here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final parameter here is misnamed:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect(host, user, pass, table);
```

It denotes name of MySQL database (e.g. "test") rather than name of a table (e.g. "test.donors" or "donors.donors").

The `_res` suffix is superfluous and may be safely elided:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $username_res, $activated_res, $expiration_res);
```

> want to make sure it is secure against SQL injection.

Yes, you are using the API as recommended, in secure fashion.

Comment: I agree with this answer. It's a simple bit of code, not much can go wrong.

Comment: The $con was just an example. Thanks for the response and the reassurance I did things correctly